# Where does Samsung's Studio app store cut videos?

Tags: samsung, storage, gallery, media-files

I'm on a Samsung Galaxy S21 FE, Android 14, One UI 6, using the built-in "Studio" app that launches by default when you edit a video through the gallery. When I edit a video I took, specifically trimmed it, I can edit it back to its original length. This can be done weeks after the edit.

How does the app achieve this - is the original video stored somewhere forever?

This would namely explain why my storage was bloated with more than 75Gb of "System storage". As a musician, I take long videos which I edit in short snippets, and have no interest in this reverse edit functionality most of the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the features of Samsung's Gallery app, as discussed [here](https://eu.community.samsung.com/t5/galaxy-s22-series/s22-video-editor-leaving-large-unedited-file-on-phone-filling-up/td-p/5669241):

The Samsung Gallery app keeps a copy of every image and video that the user edits to be able to revert the edited media back to their original version. This backed-up copy is hidden from the user and can not be deleted unless the edited version is deleted too (this is even resistant to renaming and moving files, it must be using some sort of checksum). The used storage appears under the "Other" category on the Android storage settings page.

There are two solutions to the issue:

1. Always save edited media with the "Save as copy" option, then delete the original;
2. Download the [Media File Guardian](https://apps.samsung.com/appquery/appDetail.as?appId=com.samsung.android.mediaguardian) app, which allows you to delete these hidden files.

I will use solution 1. for my future videos. However thanks to the Media File Guardian app, I was able to regain 50 GB of storage.